# Split a string and retain character position

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a large character string (`nvarchar(MAX)`) that I am trying to split 2 and identify which part of the original string they are.

Example

String:

```
5;718;0;1071;1.23|0;750;0;997;1.25|0;750;0;997;1.25|0;750;0;997;1.25|0;750;0;997;1.25|0;750;0;997;1.25
```

I would first need to split the strings based on the `'|'` character so something like this:

```
5;718;0;1071;1.23

0;750;0;997;1.25

0;750;0;997;1.25

0;750;0;997;1.25

0;750;0;997;1.25

0;750;0;997;1.25
```

I would then to split each of those based on the `';'` character:

So `5;718;0;1071;1.23` would then split into:

```
5
718
0
1071
1.23
```

I know I could do a string_split on the `'|'` then another string_split on the ';' but that does not maintain an order or identify from which portion of the string the result is split from and I am unfortunately not quite able to get the results I am looking for when trying to use `OPENJSON()`:

Based on the example above I would need a result that could identify that the `718` was from the first group and the 2nd item in said group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option that will parse your string and maintain the sequence

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = '5;718;0;1071;1.23|0;750;0;997;1.25|0;750;0;997;1.25|0;750;0;997;1.25|0;750;0;997;1.25|0;750;0;997;1.25'

Select Seq1 = A.RetSeq
      ,Val1 = A.RetVal
      ,Seq2 = B.RetSeq
      ,Val2 = B.RetVal
 From  [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse](@S,'|') A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse](A.RetVal,';') B
```

**Returns**

[image]

**The Function if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = row_number() over (order by 1/0)
          ,RetVal = ltrim(rtrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@String,@Delimiter,'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
```

**EDIT - Update for TABLE**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,SomeCol varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'5;718;0;1071;1.23|0;750;0;997;1.25|0;750;0;997;1.25|0;750;0;997;1.25|0;750;0;997;1.25|0;750;0;997;1.25')


Select A.ID
      ,Seq1 = B.RetSeq
      ,Val1 = B.RetVal
      ,Seq2 = C.RetSeq
      ,Val2 = C.RetVal
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse](SomeCol,'|') B
 Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse](B.RetVal,';') C
```

Comment: Would I be correct in assuming that I could pass a column thru that function in place of specifying each individual string?

Comment: @Tom Absolutely.  It would be in a as a cross apply.   One moment and I'll update my answer

Comment: @Tom See EDIT - Update for Table

Answer (score 0):

here's my old school take:

```
declare @v nvarchar(max) = N'5;718;0;1071;1.23|0;750;0;997;1.25|0;750;0;997;1.25|0;750;0;997;1.25|0;750;0;997;1.25|0;750;0;997;1.25'


select a.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') [value], v2.col, rnInternal,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by rnInternal order by rnInternal, Split.a) rnExternal
from 
(
    select cast('<M>' + REPLACE(v.[value], ';', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) as col, rnInternal
    from 
    (
        select 
            a.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') [value],
            ROW_NUMBER() over(order by Split.a) rnInternal
        from
            (select cast('<M>' + REPLACE(@v, '|', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) as col) as A
            CROSS APPLY A.col.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
        where
            a.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') <> ''
    ) v
) v2
CROSS APPLY v2.col.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
order by rnInternal, rnExternal
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right about the `STRING_SPLIT()` (as is mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) *the output rows might be in any order*), but you may use a JSON-based approach to get the expected results.

You need to transform the input text into a valid nested JSON array (`5;718;0;1071;1.23|0;750;0;997;1.25|` into `[[5,718,0,1071,1.23],[0,750,0,997,1.25]]`) and parse this array with two `OPENJSON()` calls using a default schema. The result from the `OPENJSON()` call is a table with columns `key`, `value` and `type` and in case of JSON array the `key` column returns the index of the element in the specified array:

```
DECLARE @text nvarchar(max) = N'5;718;0;1071;1.23|0;750;0;997;1.25|0;750;0;997;1.25|0;750;0;997;1.25|0;750;0;997;1.25|0;750;0;997;1.25'

SELECT 
   CONVERT(int, j1.[key]) + 1 AS id1,
   CONVERT(int, j2.[key]) + 1 AS id2,
   j2.[value]
FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('[[', REPLACE(REPLACE(@text, '|', '],['), ';', ','), ']]')) j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value]) j2
ORDER BY CONVERT(int, j1.[key]), CONVERT(int, j2.[key])
```

Result:

```
id1 id2 value
1   1   5
1   2   718
1   3   0
1   4   1071
1   5   1.23
2   1   0
2   2   750
...
6   1   0
6   2   750
6   3   0
6   4   997
6   5   1.25
```

If you want to identify the id's of each group and subgroup, you need to add an appropriate `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT 
   CONVERT(int, j1.[key]) + 1 AS id1,
   CONVERT(int, j2.[key]) + 1 AS id2
FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('[[', REPLACE(REPLACE(@text, '|', '],['), ';', ','), ']]')) j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value]) j2
WHERE j2.[value] = '718'
ORDER BY CONVERT(int, j1.[key]), CONVERT(int, j2.[key])
```

Result:

```
id1 id2
1   2
```